# How to insert to std::map which is in std::multimap?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, copy, stdmap

How can I insert another map into the map?

In the code, I try to copy the map from another.

```
multimap<string, map<size_t, size_t>> sorted;

for (auto itr = m_Items.begin(); itr != m_Items.end(); ++itr)
    sorted.emplace(itr->first
        , make_pair(itr->second.m_Date.m_Time, itr->second.m_Cnt)
    );
```

Comment: In the same way as you would insert any object. You seem to have written some code. Does it not do what you want?

Comment: do you really want multimap here though?

Comment: @Martin98 providing [mcve] is a good practice on SO: https://godbolt.org/z/Gh4ssT83K please provide it next time so it is easier to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have `m_Items` as

```
struct Date {
    std::size_t m_Time;
};

struct MyStruct
{
    Date m_Date;
    std::size_t m_Cnt;
};

std::multimap<std::string, MyStruct> m_Items;
```

then you need to

```
for (auto itr = m_Items.begin(); itr != m_Items.end(); ++itr)
sorted.emplace(itr->first, std::map<size_t, size_t>{ {itr->second.m_Date.m_Time, itr->second.m_Cnt} });
//                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Your map's value is again a map (i.e. `std::map<size_t, size_t>`) not a `std::par`. Therefore, you need to insert as above.

---

In [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) with the help of [structured binding declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding), and with a [range based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)(since [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)), you could write much intuitive:

```
for (const auto& [key, value] : m_Items)
  sorted.emplace(key, std::map<size_t, size_t>{ {value.m_Date.m_Time, value.m_Cnt} });
//                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Here is a **([short demo.](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/fWxfv6qvf))**

---

However, if you only need an unsorted key-value as pair as entry in `sorted`, I would suggest a

```
std::multimap<std::string, std::pair<size_t, size_t>> sorted;
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

instead there.

Comment: Just that I need sorted keys. I would also like to ask how I can list the elements in the cycle somehow I can't

Comment: I already have it using two for cycles

Answer (score 0):

To use emplace you must match arguments of pair. Second argument must be a map.

So this can be done this way:

```cpp
    multimap<string, map<size_t, size_t>> sorted;

    for (auto itr = m_Items.begin(); itr != m_Items.end(); ++itr) {
        sorted.emplace(itr->first, map{make_pair(itr->second.m_Date.m_Time,
                                                 itr->second.m_Cnt)});
    }
```

https://godbolt.org/z/aK39haYz1